# Testing Ember (v1.0.0-rc.3) nested controllers using Mocha and Chai

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write test cases for controllers of an Ember (v1.0.0-rc.3) Application using Mocha and Chai. One of my controller is making use of another controller as follows

```
App.ABCController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['application'],

  welcomeMSG: function () {
    return 'Hi, ' + this.get('controllers.application.name');
  }.property(),
  ...
  });
```

I wrote testCase as below:

```
  describe 'ABCController', ->
  expect = chai.expect
  App = require '../support/setup'
  abcController = null

  before ->
    App.reset()
    ApplicationController = require 'controllers/application_controller'
    ABCController = require 'controllers/abc_controller'
    applicationController = ApplicationController.create()
    abcController = ABCController.create()

  describe '#welcomeMSG', ->
    it 'should return Hi, \'user\'.', ->
      msg = abcController.get('welcomeMSG')
      expect(msg).to.be.equal('Hi, '+ applicationController.get('name'))

support/setup file is as follows
Em.testing = true
App = null
Em.run ->
  App = Em.Application.create()
module.exports = App
```

Now whenever i try to run testcase i face error

```
    "Before all" hook:
TypeError: Cannot call method 'has' of null
    at verifyDependencies (http://localhost:3333/test/scripts/ember.js:27124:20)
    at Ember.ControllerMixin.reopen.init (http://localhost:3333/test/scripts/ember.js:27141:9)
    at superWrapper [as init] (http://localhost:3333/test/scripts/ember.js:1044:16)
    at new Class (http://localhost:3333/test/scripts/ember.js:10632:15)
    at Function.Mixin.create.create (http://localhost:3333/test/scripts/ember.js:10930:12)
    at Function.Ember.ObjectProxy.reopenClass.create (http://localhost:3333/test/scripts/ember.js:11756:24)
    at Function.superWrapper (http://localhost:3333/test/scripts/ember.js:1044:16)
    at Context.eval (test/controllers/abc_controller_test.coffee:14:47)
    at Hook.Runnable.run (test/vendor/scripts/mocha-1.8.2.js:4048:32)
    at next (test/vendor/scripts/mocha-1.8.2.js:4298:10)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. I will appreciate if someone provide me few links where i can study for latest ember.js application testing with mocha and chai.

Comment: should this line not read `expect(msg).to.equal('Hi, '+ applicationController.get('name'))`? What I mean is using `to.equal` instead of `to.be.equal`

Answer (score 0):

Reading trough the [docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) I guess your problem is that your `expect` fails due to this `to.be.equal`. Try changing the assertion chain to this:

```
expect(msg).to.equal('Hi, '+ applicationController.get('name'))
```

**Update**

After reading your comment I guess the problem in your case is that when you do `Ember.testing = true` is equivalent to the before needed `App.deferReadiness()`, so it' obviously necessary to 'initialize' your App before using it, this is done with `App.initialize()` inside your global `before` hook. And lastly you call `App.reset()` inside your `beforeEach` hook's.

Please check also this [blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/04/21/ember-1-0-rc3.html) for more info on the update that introduced this change.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, But this is not solution to my problem, It's with ember.

Comment: maybe you are missing `App.initialize()` instead of `App.reset()`? Because if you use `Ember.testing = true` you need to call `App.initialize()` directly in the global `before` hook. `App.reset()` is what you then call inside your `before each` hook.